# UItableView sorted by date in sections (and persistence)

Tags: uitableview, date

I have several HistoryItems which contain an ID, Title and Date.
The Date is an NSDate of the exact time it was added to the history down to the second.

At the moment I just have an NSArray of these objects, the latest HistoryItem added to the end of the NSArray.

How do I make these items display in a UItableView cell in order of date, the latest being in the top, but also each day must have it's own section.

I also need these HistoryItems to be persistent between exit and loading of apps, so should I go with just saving the NSArray to a file, or using CoreData?

Comment: I am trying do the same, do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do have a vague idea but I'm not at my laptop right now so I'll edit when I get home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using CoreData will probably be easier since you can use `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the sections 'automatically'. Actually using a `NSDate` as a sectionKeyPath can be a bit problematic but as luck has it Apple has some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) that you should be able to modify from having a section per month to a section per day.

Going with CoreData also gives you the sorting essentially for free.