# Tableview with sections per day (with Core Data)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I have quite an ordinary RSS-reader type App.
The objects in the Core Data have a pubDate attribute which is the exact date + time of publishing. Using this for sections gives every article its own section.

Therefore I added a transient attribute:

```
@dynamic sectionDay;

-(NSString *) sectionDay {  
    // Get the date, and convert it to the day (counld probably be done a bit more scientific!)
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the required date format
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    // Set the values;
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.pubDate]; 

    return dateString;
}
```

Then in the FetchedResultsController I added sectionDay as the sectionNameKeyPath

```
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pubDay" ascending:NO] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionDay" cacheName:nil];
```

The problem is that I get an "ojbc_exception_throw" on NSFetchedResultsController PerformFetch:

*

```
#0  0x012165a8 in objc_exception_throw
#1  0x00eba676 in -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:]
#2  0x00df2a78 in -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:]
#3  0x00df2881 in -[NSSQLAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:]
#4  0x00df272e in -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:]
#5  0x00df1ab5 in -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:]
#6  0x00df166e in -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:]
#7  0x00ea10ec in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
#8  0x00dee807 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
#9  0x00ed2c10 in -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]
#10 0x0000456e in -[ArticleController getArticles] at ArticleController.m:92
```

*

Any suggestions what I do wrong?

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4240210, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4418703

Comment: please post the exception message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Solution in first comment by BoltClock!**

As transient properties are not stored in the database, there is no way for the fetched results controller to query for them with sql statements.(your error message)

A possible solution would be to additionally store a normalized date (remove the time component, set to 00:00:00) to group entries by date without time.

Apple recommends this type of solution in some cases, like storing normalized strings for searching

Comment: Transient properties can still be used here, the date strings used for table sections just need to be computed based on the actual `pubDate` attribute, instead of being queried from the persistent store. Of course, this answer is an equally alright way of going about it.

Comment: You are right, just had a look at the documentation of NSFetchedResultsController. Just for grouping sections, my solution seems to be a little overkill

Comment: I got the App working with the transient properties, as was suggested i other posts. Thanks for the confirmation that it should work! I must have made a type in my first attempt and it works now!

Comment: Nah I don't think it's overkill. It's fine!